# Can't connect to FTP or SSH URLs in my Azure app service API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have verified that FTP is turned on. I get this error when trying to connect in FileZilla:

> Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor
> servname provided, or not known".

My FTP URL looks like this:

```
ftp://dev-api.ase-name-dev.appserviceenvironment.net
```

> Hmmm… can't reach this pageCheck if there is a typo in
> dev-api.scm.ase-name-dev.appserviceenvironment.net.
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

This is what that URL looks like:

```
https://dev-api.scm.ase-name-dev.appserviceenvironment.net/webssh/host
```

I have two domains for this API. The default one and a new custom one. I looked in the domain settings and it all looks fine.

[image]

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above information shared, we understood that you are using app service environment.

If your app service environment is created with ILB then you need to use internal load balancer IP to do FTP adding to that you need to have any of these ports opened 21, 990, 10001-10020 as mentioned in this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info#inbound-and-outbound-dependencies).

If your ASE is created with external Load balancer then you need to use the public IP address of the ASE to perform SSH or FTP.